# T-SQL- include sum of count(*) in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Using table i and the fields date_entered and code, I wrote a query to list a count for each year where code = '12A'.

```
select distinct year(date_entered) as Yr, count(*) as Cnt
from i
where code = '12A'
group by year(date_entered)
order by Yr desc
```

This produces:

```
Yr   |    Cnt
2011   |  780
2010   |  3489
2009   |  3256
...
```

I want to include a sum of the Cnt variable in my result set.  I know how to find the sum using a separate query, but I would like to calculate the sum in my original query.

Comment: Note: The `distinct` in the query is superflous, as you are grouping on the year, all records are already unique.

Comment: @Guffa - `distinct`  and `group by` seemed to be the most misunderstood concepts in TSQL.  I've seen people group by 20 different columns just to get the "right" data.  :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `WITH ROLLUP` to the query after the `GROUP BY` clause and you'll get an extra row with a NULL Yr that contains your final total.

```
select year(date_entered) as Yr, count(*) as Cnt
from i
where code = '12A'
group by year(date_entered)
with rollup
order by Yr desc
```

Comment: The OP might want to do calculations including the count though (like percentages) Edit: Clearly not from the comment above so +1.

Comment: Why GROUP BY as well as DISTINCT?

Comment: @Dems - I think Joe was just copying and pasting. You don't need the distinct.  I've edited the answer that Joe provided to show this.

Comment: @JonH: Thanks for the cleanup. I did indeed blindly copy/paste from the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the misuse of distinct.  I have much to learn.

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT YEAR(date_entered) AS yr,
                COUNT(*)           AS cnt
         FROM   i
         WHERE  code = '12A'
         GROUP  BY YEAR(date_entered))
SELECT yr,
       cnt,
       SUM(cnt) OVER () AS totcnt
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY yr DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a sub query and include the results in your main query

```
select 
      year(date_entered) as Yr, 
      count(*) as Cnt, 
      t.MySum 
from 
      i     
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                  SUM(MyColumn) as MySum 
            FROM 
                  i                
            WHERE 
                  code='12A'
            ) t 
ON 
      t.ID = MyTable.ID
where 
      code = '12A' 
group by 
      year(date_entered) 
order by 
      Yr desc
```