# Sum SQL Server Count column from Grouped query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am trying to write a query that takes all content from my database that has been rated higher than 3 stars and returns the top four modules based on star average and highest numbers of ratings. This part works great.

But in order for me to put this into a graph, I need the percentage. So, I need the summary of the `count(id_module)` column. I have read through a lot of posts and tried to implement a number of solutions but have not been successful - can anyone shed any light for me? I have pasted my query below and the results it brings back - this part works fine... I just need to know how to get the sum of the id module fields - which in this case would be 23... thanks for any help offered!

```
SELECT TOP 4 
    AVG(rating) AS ratingstars, 
    COUNT(id_module) AS countmodules,  
FROM 
    [db]
WHERE 
    (rating > 3)
GROUP BY 
    id_module 
ORDER BY 
    ratingstars DESC, countmodules DESC
```

- ratingstars = 5, 5, 5, 5
- countstar =  18, 2, 2, 1  (need the sum of these)

Comment: You can't just do SUM(Count(Id_module)) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL- include sum of count(\*) in single query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540540/t-sql-include-sum-of-count-in-single-query)

Comment: sounds like you might want to use `Count(id_module) Over ()`

Comment: @JonH - that was what I was hoping for, it made the most sense :)  But it generates this error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: @JamieD77 - thanks for the suggestion, I am looking at this, but since I am trying to sum a grouped number that is being counted within the query, I am not sure how to implement, or if I can.  I found a tutorial I am looking over - thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: `count() over(partition by [group fields])`

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008+ you can use `SUM() OVER()`. I'm not sure if this is available in SQL Server 2005.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT TOP 4 
        AVG(rating) AS ratingstars, 
        COUNT(id_module) AS countmodules
    FROM [db]
    WHERE (rating > 3)
    GROUP BY id_module 
    ORDER BY ratingstars DESC, countmodules DESC
)
SELECT
    ratingstars
    ,countmodules
    ,SUM(countmodules) OVER () AS SumCountModules
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ratingstars DESC, countmodules DESC
;
```

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you so much!  I learned something new today :)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you found my answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this or a sub select:

```
SELECT ratingstars, SUM(countmodules) as [countmodules] FROM
(
SELECT TOP 4 AVG(rating) AS ratingstars, COUNT(id_module) AS countmodules,FROM   [db],
WHERE 
(rating > 3)
GROUP BY id_module) X
GROUP BY X.ratingstars
ORDER BY X.ratingstars DESC, X.countmodules DESC
```

Comment: or you can do the above comment, that could work to.

Comment: OK, I tried this code and I got one error: Column 'x.ratingstars' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. - so I added a it to the GROUP BY line (GROUP BY id_module, x.ratingstars) and then I got this error: The multi-part identifier "x.ratingstars" could not be bound.

Comment: Oh yeah, add this add the end. We doing aggregate function so yeah we need the group by: Just add this before the order by GROUP BY X.ratingstars

Comment: OK, I added it, but am still getting an error: The multi-part identifier "x.ratingstars" could not be bound.

Comment: Here is the last line: `  GROUP BY id_module, x.ratingstars) x ORDER BY x.ratingstars DESC, x.countmodules DESC `

Comment: Yeah the group by must go outside the "X" table: Here we go: SELECT 
 ratingstars, 
 SUM(countmodules) as [countmodules], 
 id_module 
FROM ( 
 SELECT TOP 4
  AVG(rating) AS ratingstars, 
  COUNT(id_module) AS countmodules, 
  id_module 
 FROM [pwf].[dbo].[ratings_assignments] 
  WHERE ( rating > 3 ) 
 GROUP BY id_module
 ) x 
GROUP BY x.ratingstars
ORDER BY x.ratingstars DESC, x.countmodules DESC

Comment: Basically it can't be bound as the table at that stage does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that is very helpful.  I had to change it just a little because I got another error, but I think I have it right now, the table is being pulled back...  the only problem is I don't "see" the total (I am working directly in SQL2008) the table has the totals for each module (as in the original post) - but there is no "grand" total (of 23 in this case)...  btw, here is the change I made in the GROUP BY ....   GROUP BY id_module) x GROUP BY x.ratingstars, x.countmodules, id_module

Comment: I see so the result you want is this: 4 rows with 2 columns, 1st col 5,5,5,5 comma representing a row and then column 2 23,23,23,23?

Comment: Not exactly, I am looking for 1st col 5,5,5,5   :   2nd col  18, 2, 2, 1  :   new total column that would give the sum of all values in the second column, so in this case, 23 - is that possible?

Comment: Oh yeah we can, we will then have 3 columns. the first 2 as you mentioned and then the 3rd one will have the overall total. so it will still be 5,5,5,5 | 18,2,2,1 | 23,23,23,23, will that help? I am just creating your output in a DB so I can do a proper script

Comment: Thank you so much for spending time on this!  I learned a lot from you and can apply that to other scripts - so thank you!  I have decided to go with @Vladimir Baranov 's solution below as that works, too.  Thank you again!

Comment: @DuNNi_99 Once you take only `top 4` rows in the inner query you'll lose other rows that should have contributed to the sum.

Comment: @shawnt00, yeah you actually right good point. at least problem solved!!  No stress my pleasure, sorry couldn't be more of a help

Comment: @DuNNi_99 Actually I just realized OP may want it that way.

Comment: @shawnt00 yeah actaully they do judging by the sum they gave. Quick question you should be able to do the sum over like Vladimir's solution with the inline table like mine?

Comment: @DuNNi_99 Yes, it doesn't have to be a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 4 
    AVG(rating) AS ratingstars, 
    COUNT(*) AS countmodules,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS allmodules /* <-- OVER () makes the double aggregate "ok" */
FROM 
    [db]
WHERE 
    rating > 3
GROUP BY 
    id_module 
ORDER BY 
    ratingstars DESC, countmodules DESC
```

Note this won't limit the sum to just the top four rows as I have realized you may want to do.

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful to see the different types of code!  This one gives me the total modules.  In the project I am working on I only needed the modules that were found grouped, counted and summed, but I am keeping this code as I think I will have future use - thank you so much for your time :)